# Very simple Datagrid example not working

Tags: wpf, vb.net, xaml, data-binding, datagrid

**SOLVED** Thanks to Clemens.  I just needed to add the "Property" attribute after the word "Public" in my class definition:

---

In VB.NET I'm trying to make a very simple Datagrid example work (i.e. an example without a database connection, etc).  But no matter what I try, the Datagrid always displays the correct number of rows and the correction number of columns (and the correct column headers), but the cells are empty:

```
Public Class GeneratedImage
    Public Property AssignmentId As Integer
    Public Property DocumentPageNumber As Integer
    Public Property FullPathToImage As String

    Public Sub New(id As Integer, pg As Integer, docpath As String)
        AssignmentId = id
        DocumentPageNumber = pg
        FullPathToImage = docpath
    End Sub
End Class

Private Sub MainWindow_Loaded(sender As Object, e As System.Windows.RoutedEventArgs) Handles Me.Loaded
    Dim myList As New List(Of GeneratedImage)
    myList.Add(New GeneratedImage(1, 1, "c:\nowhere"))
    myList.Add(New GeneratedImage(2, 2, "c:\nowhere2"))
    GeneratedImagesInformationDatagrid.ItemsSource = myList
    ' GeneratedImagesInformationDatagrid.DataContext = myList
end sub
```

Then, in the XAML, I bind as follows:

```
<DataGrid x:Name="GeneratedImagesInformationDatagrid"
                              Height="500"
                              VerticalAlignment="Top"
                              ItemsSource="{Binding}"
                              Width="300">
   <DataGrid.Columns>
       <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding Path=DocumentPageNumber}"
                              Header="Pg" />
       <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding Path=AssignmentId}"
                              Header="Assignment Id" />
      <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding Path=FullPathToImage}"
                              Header="Full Path To Image" />
    </DataGrid.Columns>
   </DataGrid>
```

I've tried it with and without the "ItemsSource="{Binding}" field.
Any help appreciated!

Comment: AssignmentId, DocumentPageNumber and FullPathToImage must be [properties](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/65zdfbdt.aspx?cs-save-lang=1&cs-lang=vb#code-snippet-1), not fields. WPF data binding workds with public properties only. Use [auto-implemented properties](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/dd293589.aspx) for simplicity.

Comment: Thank you, Clemens!   That did the trick.  I looked for many examples on the net, and must not have noticed that "Property" attribute.   I've also looked into Auto-implemented properties, as you suggest.   Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**SOLVED** Thanks to Clemens.  I just needed to add the "Property" attribute after the word "Public" in my class definition:

```
Public Class GeneratedImage
    Public Property AssignmentId As Integer
    Public Property DocumentPageNumber As Integer
    Public Property FullPathToImage As String
          .
          . etc
```

etc...